# STM32 interrupt does not fire

Tags: stm32, interrupts, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I'm using an STM32F103C8T6 (aka blue pill).

GPIO Init and interrupt handler:

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC13 PC15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);

  while(1);

}

void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_0);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14);
}
```

The problem is that the interrupt handler (EXTI0_IRQHandler) is never called. I tried also with other pins (e.g. using EXTI15_10_IRQHandler). I checked the switch and LED separately (in the main function) and those work.
I also tried with PULLUP and PULLDOWN (which makes no difference).

Is there more needed to trigger the interrupt function?

Comment: not sure, but is it maybe necessary to globally enable interrupts, or assign a priority to your specific interrupt? Is `EXTI0_IRQn` a constant or should it be something like `EXTI0_IRQ0`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is a constant and I will check for setting a priority, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks ... I will check,   __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE(); I already did (also for GPIOC and GPIOD.

Comment: @Marcus Müller - did you ever have any contact with those micros? I think you did not

Comment: @PeterJ I don't know why you're being so rude, I explicitly uttered a vague suspicion. Yes, I've been working with stm32f1 before, but without the clunky HAL lib. Excuse me if I don't have the docs to all the microcontrollers I've worked with in my head.

Comment: @Marcus Müller it is a general knowledge about STM micros. `EXTI0_IRQn a constant or should it be something like EXTI0_IRQ0` ???? `I've been working with stm32f0 before, but without the clunky HAL lib.` those two do not have anything in common. Those definitions are part of the CMSIS used by the bare register coders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the steps from my comment, Here is the sample code. I had a different hardware connections so I used a different pins.

```
int main(void) {
    RCC->APB2ENR = RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;


    //confure PB2  PC13 as inputs, PB0 output

    AFIO->EXTICR[0] = AFIO_EXTICR1_EXTI2_PB;
    AFIO->EXTICR[3] = AFIO_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC;
    EXTI->IMR = EXTI_IMR_MR2 | EXTI_IMR_MR13;
    EXTI->RTSR = EXTI_RTSR_TR2;
    EXTI->FTSR = EXTI_FTSR_TR13;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
    while (1);
} 
void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void) {
    if (EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR2) {
        EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR2;
        GPIOB -> ODR |= GPIO_ODR_0;
    }
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {
    if (EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR13) {
        EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR13;
        GPIOB -> ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_0;            
    }
}
```

one pin turns led on another turns off

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I use HAL so I first need to find out what all those numbers mean (good exercise for me). Btw, is there a reason you use PC13 as input since for my board PC13 is connected to an output (builtin LED)?

Comment: I havw only one board with 103 as it is an obsolete family of micros. And on this board I have different connections than the "bluepil". Just change to the one you have. I just wanted to give you the **working** example - so I have tested it on my actual hardware

Comment: When I came home it suddenly worked (only change: I took the breadboard including stm32 by car) ... so maybe it was some electronic problem (loose wire). But I will study your example to see the difference between Hal and 'direct calls'.

Comment: I honestly advise the bare registers way.

Comment: You mean like in 'all cases'? Normally I program in higher level languages, and so far I like how Hal works, but I am really just started ... if this is caused by some Hal 'strange feature', than I'm probably soon not so happy with Hal anymore.

Comment: `I program in higher level languages`?? Micro controllers? C or C++ are perfect for bare register porgramming

Comment: I didn't mean it like that ... I mean, Hal looks much more easier (and of course it hides a bit of the thoughts behind it). Since February I started with Arduino (IDE), since last month STM32, I am getting deeper and deeper (nothing wrong with that, just my 'initial intended project' seems further and further away. Your code is that the Peripheral Library?

Comment: No SPL is dead and unsupported for years. Just include CMSIS headers, download the Reference Manual and enjoy :)

Comment: I will check (but sorry I will not rule out HAL / CubeMx yet)

Comment: For those who want to read the explanation about this answer: http://embedded-lab.com/blog/stm32-external-interrupt/